# is microsoft bot framework bot builder SDK V4 production ready?

Tags: botframework

I've been seeing changes in the Enterprise Bot template and Basic Bot template. Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like something you should ask Microsoft, not random internet people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v4 Framework is indeed production ready. As with any framework, it is constantly being improved upon, and when those improvements cause bugs, they might lead to changes in the templates. If any of the improvements break production bots, you are more then welcome to seek help either here or on our [Github repos](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples).  (Source: am Microsoft bot framework person)

Comment: Not dead, just a typo. Sorry bout that. I'll get it fixed.